# Evaluation Symbol: Consistent Implementation

Tags: math-mode, symbols, delimiters, mathjax

*This question has been posted several times but...*

I'm looking for a consistent implementation of the evaluation symbol:

- Evaluation bar as delimeter: `<...>|`
- Auto-size to its enclosing expression: `\left<...>\right`

What I'm **not** looking for is:

- Evaluation bar as relation: `<...>\mid`
- Manual-size to its enclosing expression: `<...>bigg|`
- A whole macro!

Now, the problem is that `\rvert` does not auto-size, whereas `\left.` inserts extra spacing.

Perfect would be something of the form `\left_` telling latex to enclose the expression here while inserting no delimiter from the left at all, no matter wether visible or invisible.

Do you have an idea how to implement the evaluation bar?
*(Not just circumventing the problem!)*

As an example consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y(a)&=\frac12 x^2|_a\\
y(a)&=\frac12 x^2\rvert_a\\
y(a)&=\left.\frac12 x^2\right|_a
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: '\left.<stuff>\right\rvert_{<more stuff>}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: That is bad as it does not avoid the missing delimiter but inserts an invisible delimiter.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Freeze_S I am not sure you understand: it's your duty to make LaTeX aware of the delimiters, not the other way around (unfortunately...).

Comment: @cfr: Of course, one moment, please.

Comment: In general autoscaling is not a good idea. I'd make a macro where you add manual scaling via an optional argument. Autoscaling often ends up being too large

Comment: @daleif: But manual scaling sort of contradicts the principles of latex: Latex does the job for you.

Comment: @daleif why is autoscaling not a good idea?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: The problem is that I'd need a no-delimiter argument. I don't know what to answer on this: I know what a computer is. ;)

Comment: @daleif: I'm sorry, my deleted comment was actually adressed to MarcvanDongen.

Comment: @Freeze_S Do you need just the subscript or also the superscript?

Comment: @egreg: For myself: Subscript only.

Comment: @Freeze_S In LaTeX terms, `\rvert` is a delimeter.

Comment: Try adding the auto scaling principle to `\sum_j`, that just get too large. You will find other people here how also advise against general autoscaling. Autoscaling should be used when appropriate, but not in every single case, that will end up biting you.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Yep but `\rvert` does not autoscale and `\left.` adds an invisible delimiter. Perfect would be something like `\left_` instead of `\left.` telling latex to enclose the expression here and not to insert any delimiter from the left no matter wether visible or invisible.

Comment: @Freeze_S We're probably missing each other's point. Final attempt: _no_ delimiter autoscales. Delimiters only autoscale with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a macro that does auto scaling, but also allows you to manually specify a size if so desired. You can also specif a prefix for the limits if so desired as in the last example on the first group:

[image]

### Notes:

- The manually specified size example as just illustrate the possibilities in the size that you can select. I am not suggesting that all those sizes are appropriate for the given fraction.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38868/big-parenthesis-in-an-equation
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/about-big-parenthesis-larger-than-bigg
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{3}}
    \newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{3.5}}
    \newcommand{\vastt}{\bBigg@{4}}
    \newcommand{\Vastt}{\bBigg@{4.5}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\BracKern}{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Eval}{O{} o m m m}{%
    % #1 = prefix to be added to each limit of evaluation (ex "x=").
    % #2 = optional size specification to be applied (defaults to \left \right pair)
    %          \big \Big \bigg \Bigg \vast \Vast \vastt \Vastt
    %
    % #3 = expression being evaluated
    % #4 = lower limit of evaluation
    % #5 = upper limit of evaluation
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
        \left.\BracKern#3\right\rvert_{#1#4}^{#1#5}%
    }{%
        #3#2\rvert_{#1#4}^{#1#5}%
    }%
}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Automatically sized:
\begin{gather*}
    \Eval{x^2}{0}{5} \quad
    \Eval{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5} \quad
    \Eval[x=]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5} 
\end{gather*}
Manually sized
\begin{gather*}
    \Eval[][\big]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}    \quad
    \Eval[][\Big]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}    \quad
    \Eval[][\bigg]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}   \quad
    \Eval[][\Bigg]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}   \quad
    \Eval[][\vast]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}   \quad
    \Eval[][\Vast]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}   \quad
    \Eval[][\vastt]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}  \quad
    \Eval[][\Vastt]{\frac{1}{x}}{0}{5}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aaah, but for mathjax? *(I'm using it mostly for SE.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S I'm afraid that mathjax is off-topic for this site...

Comment: @Freeze_S if you want to re-implement this solution in MathJax, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

An application of the macros in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136767/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xDeclarePairedDelimiter}{mmmO{}}
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{sO{}m}
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}
     {
      \egreg_paired_delimiter_expand:nnnn {#2}{#3}{##3}{#4}
     }
     {
      \egreg_paired_delimiter_fixed:nnnnn {##2}{#2}{#3}{##3}{#4}
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_paired_delimiter_expand:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {% Fix the spacing issue with \left and \right (D. Arsenau, P. Stephani and H. Oberdiek)
  \mathopen{}
  \mathclose\c_group_begin_token
   \left#1
   \str_if_eq:nnT { . } { #1 } { \kern-\nulldelimiterspace }
   #3
   \group_insert_after:N \c_group_end_token
   \right#2
   \tl_if_empty:nF {#4} { \c_math_subscript_token {#4} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_paired_delimiter_fixed:nnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF {.} { #2 } { \mathopen{#1#2} }
  #4
  \mathclose{#1#3}
  \tl_if_empty:nF {#5} { \c_math_subscript_token {#5} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% the final optional argument to \xDeclarePairedDelimiter
%% is a subscript to the right fence
\xDeclarePairedDelimiter{\xeval}{.}{\rvert}[\evaluateat]
\newcommand{\evaluateat}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{somm}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\evaluateat}{#4}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\xeval*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\xeval{#3}}{\xeval[#2]{#3}}}%
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y(a)&=\eval{\tfrac{1}{2}x^2}{a}\\
y(a)&=\eval[\Big]{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{a}\\
y(a)&=\eval[\bigg]{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{a}\\
y(a)&=\eval*{\dfrac{1}{2}x^2}{a}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\eval` is for choosing manually a size; `\eval*` is like using `\left` and `\right`. The second argument is the point of evaluation.

[image]

Comment: Aah, but isn't a macro kind of overshot?

Comment: @Freeze_S Why? To the contrary, it guarantees uniformity!

Comment: True, but isn't there a simpler way e.g. sth. like `\left_` instead of `\left.` inserting no delimiter at all?