# Math-Mode: No-Delimiter

Tags: math-mode, symbols, delimiters

This is a subquestion related to [Evaluation Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216408/54180).

Is there something of the form `\left<?>` instead of `\left.` telling LaTeX to enclose the expression here and not to insert any delimiter at all, no matter wether visible or invisible?

As an example I want:

`\left<no-delimiter><stuff>\right|_<index>`

Comment: Can you clarify your question, I can not guess what input or output you intend. If you do not want any delimiter why do you need any markup at all?

Comment: Of course, a moment, please.

Comment: looking at the referenced question it seems that you want `\left.` but after setting  `\nulldelimiterspace=0pt` Is that a correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: YES!! But doesn't `.` stand for spacing. Does there exist `\nulldelimiter`?

Comment: `\newcommand\noleft{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}`

Comment: There is no csname for the nulldelimiter just use `.` but the amount of space is configurable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Btw does it read null'delimiterspace or nulldelimiter'space? Does . really mean nodelimiter?

Comment: @Freeze_S I'm not sure I understand the distinction you make, the TeXbook says: A null delimiter isn't completely void; it is an empty box
whose width is a TeX parameter called \nulldelimiterspace.
We will see later that null delimiters are inserted next to fractions.
Plain TeX sets \nulldelimiterspace=1.2pt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah ok, so it is really the null delimiter not just a delimiter with null space around it, thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `\left.` is used, TeX inserts no delimiter, but adds a space of width `\nulldelimiterspace`. It's not advisable to set this parameter to zero, in my opinion. But with

```
\newcommand{\noleft}{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
```

using

```
\noleft x\right|_{a}
```

will in any case remove the added space.

As explained in my answer to the referenced question, using a macro would be much better for ensuring consistency. If your aim is to get code that works also with MathJax out of the box, you're on the wrong road: the capabilities of MathJax are limited and so you are forcing yourself into using bad LaTeX.

Comment: Great!! Thanks alot!! :) Btw what does `\kern` do precisely?

Comment: @Freeze_S It inserts another space, which is the negative of the kern inserted by the null delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

```
<stuff>\big|_<index>
```

is also possible. There is also `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{mleftright}
\[ x \mleft. \frac{1}{2} \mright|_i ]|
```

The package `mleftright` fixes the spacing of `\left.` and `\right|`, so that it is the same as in `$ x \frac{1}{2} |_x $` but the `|` vertically stretches as you were using `\left.` and `\right|`.

So `\mleft.` should do what you do (null delimiter, no space), but consider that the space after `\mright|` is reduced too.