# Extensible unpaired delimiter

Tags: delimiters, mathtools

Is there a variant of `mathtools`'s `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` that works for *unpaired* delimiters?  EDIT:  To be clear, I'm looking for a command that can be called as `\command{delimited}`, `\command*{delimited}`, or `\command[\big]{delimited}`, with the syntax of `DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

```
\usepackage{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\tall{\rule{0pt}{10ex}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\withblank{}\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\withdot.\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\withrelax\relax\rvert
\begin{document}
\(\withdot*\tall\) produces the same result as \(\left.\tall\right\rvert\), but \(\withdot{}\) does not produce the same result as \({}\rvert\).

\(\withblank{}\) and \(\withrelax{}\) produce the same result as \({}\rvert\), and \(\withblank*\tall\) and \(\withrelax*\tall\) both give errors (but eventually produce the same result as \(\left.\tall\right\rvert\)).
\end{document}
```

EDIT:  To be clear, as @Werner points out [below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336135/extensible-unpaired-delimiter#comment824132_336135), the behaviour of `\withdot{}` is not literally a bug; it's just not what I want.

Comment: Your first example for `\withdot{}` should be similar to `.{}\rvert`, not `{}\rvert`, so the expected output is correct.

Comment: You can't use `.` in `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. It's a misfeature of the command.

Comment: @egreg, is there any satisfactory workaround?

Comment: @LSpice Yes: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216408/evaluation-symbol-consistent-implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `\withblank` and `\withrelax` (non-starred) can't work as there is no (say) extensible `{}`. The only extensible "blank" delimiter is `.`. If you're interested in defining blank left/right delimiters that might be used in a starred form similar to what is provided by `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, the following may suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42337/5764
\begingroup\lccode`\|=`\\
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\removebs#1{\if#1|\else#1\fi}}
\newcommand{\macroname}[1]{\expandafter\removebs\string#1}

\newcommand\tall{\rule{0pt}{10ex}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\withdot.\rvert

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\withblank}{\@ifstar\withblank@\withblank@@}
\newcommand{\withblank@}[1]{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace #1\right\rvert}% \withblank*{..}
\newcommand{\withblank@@}[2][]{% \withblank[.]{..}
  #2
  \if\relax#1\relax
    \rvert
  \else
    \csname\macroname{#1}r\endcsname\rvert
  \fi}
\newcommand{\withrelax}{\withblank}% \withrelax is similar to \withblank
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(\withdot*\tall\) produces the same result as \(\left.\tall\right\rvert\).

\(\withdot{}\) produce the same result as \(.{}\rvert\).

\(\withblank{}\) and \(\withrelax{}\) is similar to \({}\rvert\).

\(\withblank[\Big]{}\) and \(\withrelax[\Big]{}\) is similar to \({}\Bigr\rvert\).

\(\withblank*\tall\) and \(\withrelax*\tall\) is similar to \(\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\tall\right\rvert\).

\end{document}
```

Note that the definition

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\withdot.\rvert
```

is odd as `\withdot{<stuff>}` would provide `.<stuff>\rvert`, and it's not clear what the `.` delimiter (that is not extended) means here.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't allow the `\command[\size]` syntax of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.  I could just copy the relevant code from `mathtools`, but I'd prefer not to do so if there's an existing solution.  Also, as you point out here and [above](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336135/extensible-unpaired-delimiter/336138#comment824132_336135), the behaviour of `\withdot` is not a bug in a literal sense; it's just not what I want.

Comment: Never mind; obviously I can't execute TeX in my head as well as TeX itself can, since testing shows that your suggestion *does* support explicit sizing.  Thank you!

Comment: @LSpice: I've added support for `\command[\size]`.