# Spacing, delimiter, and Libertinus Math

Tags: spacing, luatex, delimiters, mathtools, kerning

> The issue is possibly going to be reviewed once the version of TeX Live has been installed.

I would like to have a command that stretches the common delimiters according to the content. The standard `\sin\left(` is known to have a bad spacing, the packages https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools and https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright and the proposed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136767/128553 have a different issue with spacing. I assume that this might be related to the beautiful typeface https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus-fonts by https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729.
The project requires `LuaLaTeX`.

The problem does not occur with `XeLaTeX` with with `Latin Modern`, nor `Libertinus Math`. The problem does not occur with `LuaLaTeX` and `Latin Modern`. Both engines can be used in the MWE.

The following MWE shows some examples.

```
\documentclass[a1paper,DIV=50,12pt,landscape]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
%\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,mleftright,xparse}
%\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mleftright}


\ifcase0
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{LibertinusMath-Regular.otf}[Scale=MatchUppercase,math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]
\else
\setmainfont{lmroman12-regular}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}[Scale=MatchUppercase,math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]
\fi


\ExplSyntaxOn%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136767/128553
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\KDeclarePairedDelimiter}{mm}
 {
  \__egreg_delimiter_clear_keys: % reset to the default
  \keys_set:nn { egreg/delimiters } { #2 }
  \use:x % we want to expand the values of the token variables set with the keys
   {
    \exp_not:n {\NewDocumentCommand{#1}{sO{}m} }
     {
      \exp_not:n { \IfBooleanTF{##1} }
       {
        \exp_not:N \egreg_paired_delimiter_expand:nnnn
         { \exp_not:V \l_egreg_delimiter_left_tl }
         { \exp_not:V \l_egreg_delimiter_right_tl }
         { \exp_not:n { ##3 } }
         { \exp_not:V \l_egreg_delimiter_subscript_tl }
       }
       {
        \exp_not:N \egreg_paired_delimiter_fixed:nnnnn 
         { \exp_not:n { ##2 } }
         { \exp_not:V \l_egreg_delimiter_left_tl }
         { \exp_not:V \l_egreg_delimiter_right_tl }
         { \exp_not:n { ##3 } }
         { \exp_not:V \l_egreg_delimiter_subscript_tl }
       }
     }
   }
 }

\keys_define:nn { egreg/delimiters }
 {
  left      .tl_set:N = \l_egreg_delimiter_left_tl,
  right     .tl_set:N = \l_egreg_delimiter_right_tl,
  subscript .tl_set:N = \l_egreg_delimiter_subscript_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__egreg_delimiter_clear_keys:
 {
  \keys_set:nn { egreg/delimiters } { left=.,right=.,subscript={} }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_paired_delimiter_expand:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {% Fix the spacing issue with \left and \right (D. Arsenau, P. Stephani and H. Oberdiek)
  \mathopen{}
  \mathclose\c_group_begin_token
   \left#1
   #3
   \group_insert_after:N \c_group_end_token
   \right#2
   \tl_if_empty:nF {#4} { \c_math_subscript_token {#4} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_paired_delimiter_fixed:nnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
 {
  \mathopen{#1#2}#4\mathclose{#1#3}
  \tl_if_empty:nF {#5} { \c_math_subscript_token {#5} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\DeclareMathOperator{\mtool}{mtl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\plain}{pl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lr}{rl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mlr}{mrl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\egl}{egl}
\newcommand{\argdot}{{\hspace{0.16667em}\cdot\hspace{0.16667em}}}

\KDeclarePairedDelimiter{\knorm}{left=\lVert,right=\rVert}
\KDeclarePairedDelimiter{\kabs}{left=\lvert,right=\rvert}
\KDeclarePairedDelimiter{\kbracket}{left=(,right=)}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bracket}{(}{)}

\newcommand{\checkLetter}[1]{
    f\abs*{#1}
    \plain\lvert{}#1\rvert
        -\mtool\abs{#1}
        +\mtool\abs*{#1}
        \#\egl\kabs*{#1}
        \times\lr\left\lvert{}#1\right\rvert
        *\mlr\mleft\lvert{}#1\mright\rvert
    \quad \plain(#1)
        -\mtool\bracket{#1}
        +\mtool\bracket*{#1{}}
        \#\egl\kbracket*{#1{}}
        \times\lr\left(#1\right)
        *\mlr\mleft(#1\mright)
}
\newcommand{\checkLetterSingle}[1]{
    \checkLetter{#1}
        &=\checkLetter{\int #1}\allowdisplaybreaks\\
}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
%   {{\dot\Gamma_{r}}}_{1}^{2}\\
    \checkLetterSingle{\argdot}
    \checkLetterSingle{\argdot_{}^{}}
%   
    1\checkLetterSingle {f}
    1u\checkLetterSingle {f_{}}
    1a\checkLetterSingle {f^{}}
    1au\checkLetterSingle {f_{}^{}}
    1h\checkLetterSingle {f\hspace{1pt}}
%%
%   2\checkLetterSingle F
%   2h\checkLetterSingle {F\hspace{1pt}}
%   2a\checkLetterSingle {F^{}}
%   2u\checkLetterSingle {F_{}}
%   2au\checkLetterSingle {F_{}^{}}%    
%%
%   6\checkLetterSingle \omega
%   7\checkLetterSingle {f_\sum}
%   7a\checkLetterSingle {{f_\sum}^{}}
%   7u\checkLetterSingle {{f_\sum}_{}}
%   7au\checkLetterSingle {{f_\sum}_{}^{}}
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

A detail of the whole picture: `pl` (without anything), `mtl` (`mathtools`), `egl` (egreg's proposal), `rl` (`\left`), and `url` (`mleftright`).
[image]
The problem can be solved by manually adding hspace by try and error but I do not really like that. I consider that a dirty solution as it is time consuming and not consistent.

The problem is less prominent or not existent with Latin Modern (I do not know whether this is on purpose or not):
[image]

More examples (feel free to experiment with the code):
[image]

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929 noted that this is not a *kerning* but a *spacing* issue. Thank you. He is no longer maintainer of the typeface, see https://github.com/alerque/libertinus/issues/328.

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/alif-type/libertinus

Comment: This is a LuaTeX issue, and I’m sure there were similar questions about this here.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Thank you. That means there is not much to do about it?

Comment: @KhaledHosny But there is one thing I do not understand:  Latin Modern does not have this problem.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Thank you very much for your work in the field of TeX and its derivatives and typefaces.

Comment: @CampanIgnis: are you using the Type 1 or the OpenType version of Latin Modern Math?

Comment: @KhaledHosny: The second screenshot was produced with `\ifcase0` in the above MWE, so it uses `LuaLaTeX`’s default font:  
`name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
DFXGEI+LatinModernMath-Regular       CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0 `

Comment: @KhaledHosny I have updated the MWE and the images to ensure that I am using the OpenType font.